# how to change json property string value based on logic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a scenario where i am loading template label dynamically from external json file `en.json` using angularJs translate , Now i am launching this screen from two different places in application so i want to set labels according to screen.So when `$stateParams.assessmentId` i want to set different string but that is not happening its always returning `"Process Owner(s) Responding to Challenge:"`.

1- How can i achieve that task based on `$stateParams` or any other `json` solution ?

2- How can i access external file en.json properties and update the value ?

main.html

```
<label  class="col-md-4" translate="processChallenge.processOwnerResponse"></label>
```

en.json

```
 "processChallenge":{
             "processOwnerResToChlng":"Process Owner(s) Responding to Challenge:",
             "processOwnerResponse":"User Response:"
            },
```

ctrl.js

```
if ($stateParams.processId) {
  processChallenge.processOwnerResToChlng = "Process Owner(s) Responding to Challenge:";

} else if ($stateParams.assessmentId) {
    processChallenge.processOwnerResToChlng = "Rcsa preparer(s) Responding to Challenge:";
}
```

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: label is always refering to `"Process Owner(s) Responding to Challenge:"`

Comment: Check the value of `$stateParams.processId`

Comment: `$stateParams.processId` value is coming correct but i edited my question , so its more of how we can access external json file and update the value using angularJs controller

Comment: confusing me will you please elaborate it more

Comment: One thing that's confusing matters is that you're calling everything JSON. JSON is a format for strings. Everything else, like `$stateParams` are objects, plain and simple. As for your problem, I suggest reading [the documentation about the `translate` directive](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/05_using-translate-directive), as it mentions you can use interpolation.